# Rails 4 permalink to_param method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, parameters

Rails 4 `to_param` method is not working like Rails 3.
How can I do this? Is it a problem with strong parameters?

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{name}".downcase.gsub(/\W+/, "-").gsub(/^[-]+|[-]$/,"").strip
end
```

Comment: give us some input string that you want to use on this method.

Comment: I put this method in my user model in order to have :
localhost:3000/users/my-id-my-users-name